# When to Blindly Load Data vs Load Only Needed Data from REST server in Javascript Client

Tags: javascript, rest, optimization, latency

When using javascript on the client, it is often possible to load a whole chunk of data in one go, like `load("http://restful.server.com/api/model/")` or just load the data needed like `load("http://restful.server.com/api/model/id=1234")`. When you only need a few items, the latter makes sense. If, however, the number of needed items can vary widely, the latency of making a number of requests becomes overwhelming.

How do you determine how to structure requests to optimize load time if you cannot know in advance which approach is fastest?

To give an example, an app I am developing show the following numbers:

```
individual: Load choices based on individual questions, following the foreign
        relationship. The logical way, but costs round-trip-time.
  Min           Avg         Stddev      Max
times 77.13955832   96.59890914 23.99644340 184.17492986
sizes 0.232828M     0.238071M   0.002353M   0.241834M
speed 1.264167K     2.566590K   0.424770K   3.109053K

all: Load all choices in one go, ignoring the fact that most of them will be
     unused. Sloppy, but fast?
      Min           Avg         Stddev      Max
times 0.21781421    1.79287671  6.82427604  31.53920007
sizes 0.656552M     0.656552M   0.00000000  0.656552M
speed 0.020817M     2.746438M   0.6278713M  3.014275M
```

Note that `all` speeds are about an order of magnitude higher. This is obviously influenced by the one-hop GigE connection to the server in this test. But, with real connections showing larger minimum RTTs as well as lower throughput, it should be similar.
Once it is finished, though I expect that the size of the data available will grow by 1.3-2 orders of magnitude. That means bulk loading only works for super fast connections. What to do?

Comment: How are you getting the numbers above? Can you do it at runtime?

Comment: Do you know how many items you are going to load at runtime? If it's a lot, use bulk approach. Otherwise, load them individually. Or, maybe, I didn't understand the question.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: The user can choose how many items to load, so the number is not known in advance. Since the users will be able to add items, the total available is likely to grow significantly. And, since they are selected based on a randomish foreign key relationship, I cannot just load sequential ranges. This cannot be a unique problem, but I don't know what strategy to apply.

Comment: @AbdullahJibaly: Those are just the result of timing `curl` on my workstation. Not representative of the real world, but they demonstrate the issue.